# Increase acceleration on a vehicle

Tags: honda, acceleration, crv

I'm working with a 2011 Honda CR-V and the acceleration is abysmal. Is there a way to increase the acceleration? I've tried putting it in D3, put it in D2 and D1.

For example, if I press the pedal to the floor, there is a 3/4th to one second pause and then the engine revs and drives faster. I want to reduce or remove that pause.

It feels dangerous having so much latency in the throttle response.

**Update:**
The reason I ask is that maybe the "line" to the accelerator is too long like a hand break on a bike that has too much slack. If this could be tightened up so that there is no slack.

Or maybe there is a drive mode that it is stuck in. I've seen drive modes on numerous vehicles.

I've driven vehicles in the past that are quick to respond, and usually they have been more expensive.

Comment: Year? miles? transmission? 2 vs all wheel drive? My 2002 manual AWD had no such issues, finally sold it at 200,000 miles.

Comment: Hasn't it always driven like this? Honda's automatic transmission is the *worst* driving experience, especially in "eco" (aka "no drive") mode. Could be a range of things from minor to severe, easy fix to impossible fix. One hunch is throttle position sensor issue: https://www.autozone.com/diy/fuel-systems/how-to-diagnose-and-replace-your-throttle-position-sensor

Comment: @JonCuster 2011 2 wheel. It does accelerate slightly fast after a one second hesitation. I don't know what it is doing at the start but if I press the pedal to the floor there's that pause and then it does accelerate quickly and the engine has the revved engine sound. I want to remove that pause.

Answer (score 0):

First, replace the air filter.  Next, you likely have lots of engine deposits.  Add the following all together in the gas tank:

Marvel Mystery Oil - 4 oz. for every 10 gallons of gas.

Star Tron - 10x concentration of what's recommended on the label.  You can't overdose.

BG 44k - 1 can for every 12 gallons.

The Marvel Mystery Oil and Star Tron are available in most auto parts stores or Walmart.  The BG 44k is only available online, like [here](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07PXCTPV7) on Amazon.

I just used this combination on a CR-V a few months ago.  After a two-hour drive the throttle response was like new again.  Mix the additives during a fill-up at the gas station.  Upon first run, pump the pedal repeatedly in neutral to "wet" the cylinders (at a stop light, for instance).  Then drive at a variety of speeds:  stop-and-go traffic, five wide-open blasts on the highway (50-80 MPH), very steady 60 MPH on an open road most of the rest of the time.  I even ran the car with pedal at the floor going uphill for about 30 seconds (100 MPH), but that's optional ;-)